# C# Porque lo que ingreso da 0?

Tags: c#

Quería saber por qué cuando Console.readline no funciona dentro de la condición, cada número que ingreso no se almacena en la array. Y cuando está afuera lo hace, pero no puedo hacerlo así. Es como que la condición no dejara guardar todo lo que se ingresa p-p .

En si intente desde, ponerlo fuera de la condición, poner todo dentro de una condición, quitar el while y hacer otro método. Pero no puedo hacer eso, ya que la tarea me decía tipo menú y que debe ser infinito hasta que uno quiera cerrar el programa.

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("==========================================");
    Console.WriteLine("Ingreso= 1\nEgreso= 2\nResultados= 3\nCerrar= 0011");
    Console.WriteLine("==========================================");

    Console.Write("Elige: ");
    int Elige =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    //Variable limitador
    int Limit = 3;
    Limit++;

    int Limit1 = 1;

    //Variables globales
    int[] Ingreso = new int[Limit];
    int[] Desingreso = new int[Limit];

    //Variable numerador
    int numD = 0;
    int numI = 0;

    if (Elige == 1)
    {
        Limit1++;
        numI++;
        Console.Write("Ingresa: "); 
        Ingreso[Limit1] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (Ingreso[Limit1] < 0)
        {
            Ingreso[Limit1] = Ingreso[Limit1] * -1;
        }
    }
    else if (Elige == 2)
    {
        Limit1++;
        numD++;
        Console.Write("Desingreso: ");
        Desingreso[Limit1] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (Desingreso[Limit1] > 0)
        {
            Desingreso[Limit1] = Desingreso[Limit1] * -1;
        }
    }
    else if (Elige == 3)
    {
        //Variables de calculo

        int TotalIngreso = Ingreso.Sum();
        int TotalDesingreso = Desingreso.Sum();

        int Total = TotalIngreso - TotalDesingreso;

        Console.WriteLine("===================Acredor===================");
        for(int i = 1; i < Limit1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Ingreso:{Ingreso[i]}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Total);
    }
    else if (Elige == 0011)
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: No entendí, puedes explicarlo de otra forma y agregar un ejemplo?

Comment: Porque tus arrays se crean en cada interacción del while, es decir, funcionaa 1 vez.  Solo el teecer elemento del array  se llena  considerando que el.primero tiene índice 0.

Comment: Los arreglos y Limit, Limit1 sacalos del while y ten presente que los arreglos empiezan en el índice 0. Limit realmente tiene 4 a las finales. Dentro del while asegúrate de no pasar ese límite si los pones fuera del while.  En todo caso un for.

Comment: Muchas gracias :,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no se si entendí bien el problema pero aquí una solución que tal vez te sirva y para que puedas tener de apoyo, pero una de las razones mas visibles es que cada vez que pasa por el while tus "variables globales (ingreso y egreso)" que tienes dentro del while se resetean, compara con esta solución y adaptala a tus necesidades, espero te sirva

```
//Variables globales Fuera del while para que no se declaren en cada pasada del while
List<int> Ingreso = new List<int>();
List<int> Egreso = new List<int>();
int numIng = 0;

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("==========================================");
    Console.WriteLine("Ingreso= 1\nEgreso= 2\nResultados= 3\nCerrar= 11");
    Console.WriteLine("==========================================");

    Console.Write("Elige: ");
    int Elige = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    //Variable limitador
    //int Limit = 3;
    //Limit++;

    int Limit1 = 1;

    //Variables globales
    //int[] Ingreso = new int[Limit];
    //int[] Desingreso = new int[Limit];

    //Variable numerador
    //int numD = 0;
    //int numI = 0;

    if (Elige == 1)
    {
        //Limit1++;
        //numI++;
        Console.Write("Ingresa: ");
        numIng = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (numIng < 0)
            numIng = numIng * -1;

        Ingreso.Add(numIng);
    }
    else if (Elige == 2)
    {
        //Limit1++;
        //numD++;
        Console.Write("Desingreso: ");
        numIng = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (numIng < 0)
            numIng = numIng * -1;

        Egreso.Add(numIng);
    }
    else if (Elige == 3)
    {
        //Variables de calculo
        int TotalIngreso = Ingreso.Sum();
        int TotalDesingreso = Egreso.Sum();

        int Total = TotalIngreso - TotalDesingreso;

        Console.WriteLine("===================Acredor===================");
        for (int i = 1; i < Limit1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Ingreso:{Ingreso[i]}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Total);
        //Luego de mostrar el resultado las listas se dejan vacías
        Ingreso.Clear();
        Egreso.Clear();
    }
    else if (Elige == 11)
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    //Se resetea el numero ingresado
    numIng = 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :D